# How to add visualization of sub labels in Kibana for gauge arc based on time range split by – day, week, month and year?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've built in Kibana a gauge arc, based on time range split by – day, week, month, and year.

I am missing the labels at the bottom for each.

On the options tab, there is an option to add sub-labels but it is not dynamic.

I suspect there is an option to add Json with conditions in advanced property to add sub-labels.

Can anyone share that script?

[image]

1. I found this post but adding a field of @timestamp, time, timestamp – didn't do the job. https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/69908
2. On the options tab there is a Sub Labels – but it's not dynamic, I need to work by conditions of the time range I am in.